# SRAtoolkit not working without using home directory

Tags: ncbi

I am working with NCBI's SRAtoolkit 2.11.0 mac64. I just successfully configured the toolkit using `vdb-config -i` but I am unable to access any commands if I am not working in the bins file, using `./` before every command. This of course overrides my pre-established filepath to dump the sequence reads and instead deposits them into the bin file.

How can I use SRAtoolkit without using `./` constantly?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is having the same issue, here was my solution. I used bioinfokit (`pip install bioinfokit`). My commands in order:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/filepath/sratoolkit.2.11.0-mac64/bin
source nucelotide_venv/bin/activate
python
from bioinfokit.analys import fastq
fastq.sra_bd(file='SRR-file.txt')
for f in SRR*; do fasterq-dump $ f; done
```

I know it's clunky as heck but I'm new and it works!